# How to give padding between Select control's expanded items

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a `Select` control. I want to add margin (or padding) in expanded items (expanded area) of select control.

```
$("<select style='outline:none;' name='MaxAcceptableName'
data-value-update='MaxAcceptableText' data-bind='text: MaxAcceptableText' id='MaxAcceptableId'></select > ")
```

This is how it looks right now

[image]

I tried adding padding, margin but directly applies for select control not for the UI after opening it. How can I add margin or padding in items and for bottom item as well so that it will good look.

Comment: You can't style a `<select>` (beyond a few basics such as border) - it's rendered by the browser and will appear differently on different browsers.  Your only option is to go with a wrapper such as [tag:select2]

Comment: Here's an existing question, but all answers are relatively old and there may be newer posibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css